# SwiftUI Row Height of List - how to control?

Tags: listview, formatting, swiftui

I have a simple List in SwiftUI. Code and Screenshot included below.
I would like to reduce the height of each row in the list (so less space between lines and text lines closer together).

I already tried to add a ".frame(height: 20)" to the HStack but it only allows the line spacing to be increased!

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks!

Gerard

```
import SwiftUI

struct PressureData: Identifiable {
  let id: Int
  let timeStamp: String
  let pressureVal: Int
}

struct ContentView : View {
  @State var pressureList = [
    PressureData(id: 0, timeStamp: "11:49:57", pressureVal: 10),
    PressureData(id: 1, timeStamp: "11:49:56", pressureVal: 8),
    PressureData(id: 2, timeStamp: "11:49:55", pressureVal: 9),
    PressureData(id: 3, timeStamp: "11:49:54", pressureVal: 1),
  ]

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Pressure Readings")
            .font(.system(size: 30))
        List(pressureList) { row in
            HStack {
               Spacer()
                Text(row.timeStamp)
                Text("--->")
                Text(String(row.pressureVal))
                Spacer()
            } .frame(height: 30)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Use **Environment** variable to set min Height of the row in the list and after that change the **HStack** frame height to your desired height.

Here is the code:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Pressure Readings")
            .font(.system(size: 30))
        List(pressureList) { row in
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text(row.timeStamp)
                Text("--->")
                Text(String(row.pressureVal))
                Spacer()
            }.frame(height: 10)
        }.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 10)
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: I want to know what is the default height?

Comment: @gaohomway, The default is `nil`. When this value is `nil`, the system chooses the appropriate height.